# Pass through unknown variables to Load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple (100s) of Javascript files that use a common js file with a standard function to essentially load the response of an aspx file into a DIV on a page.
However (and this is probably blindingly obvious), the data part of the JQuery `load(URL, data, callback)` function has some set variables but I also want to be able to handle unknown variables passed to the function.

The function is as follows (cut down a bit as there are a lot of form fields)

```
function global_submitform(DIV_ID,ADDITIONAL_FIELDS)
 {
  $("#"+DIV_ID).load("functions.aspx?process=processform",
    {
    USERID, $("#userid").val(),
    NAME, $("#name").val(),
    PHONE, $("#phone").val()
    },
    function(response,status,xhr){if (status=="error"){$(#"+DIV_ID).html(xhr.status+" "+ xhr.statusText);}});
```

This works fine for the js files calling it but I'm not sure how I could add process the **ADDITIONAL_FIELDS** passthough. It would be added after `$("#phone").val()` but I get errors if I try something like `eval(ADDITIONAL_FIELDS)` as the script is no longer valid.
I could potentially just append the extra unknown variables to the url part but some of the values could be very large.

Is this possible or do I need to look at another way of doing it?

Comment: Have you tried $.extend?

Comment: Is `ADDITIONAL_FIELDS` an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show what you're passing for `ADDITIONAL_FIELDS`, but I'll guess that it's a hash.

I'll also turn the `data` parameter into a normally-written hash.

Assuming you're calling :

```
global_submitform('thediv', { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 } );
```

you'd want to combine those with your "permanent" values:

```
function global_submitform(DIV_ID,ADDITIONAL_FIELDS)
{
  var fields = ADDITIONAL_FIELDS || {};   // maybe nothing was passed
  $.extend(fields, 
    {
      USERID: $("#userid").val(),
      NAME: $("#name").val(),
      PHONE: $("#phone").val()
    }
  );

  // in our example, "fields" now contains the foo, bar, USERID, 
  // NAME and PHONE members

  $("#"+DIV_ID).load("functions.aspx?process=processform",
    fields,
    function(response,status,xhr){if (status=="error"){$(#"+DIV_ID).html(xhr.status+" "+ xhr.statusText);}});
}
```

Note that you can also just call:

```
global_submitform('thediv');
```

if you have no extra parameters.